# How to cross reference a kable which is an element of a list using rmarkdown for a pdf output?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm generating a pdf from rmarkdown with cross references to tables.This works fine when a kable is generated within a chuck. Where a kable is an element of a list, and the kable includes a caption the generated table is given a caption as expected, however, the cross reference for that table fails.

Is there a way to overcome this, and enable table cross references where a kable is an element of a list?

My actual use case is a bit more complicated in that the kable is included in a list which has been generated as an output from a local package function.

````
---
title: "Table cross references"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{float}
---


```{r dw, include=FALSE}

library(kableExtra)

ls_eg <- vector("list")

ls_eg$df1 <- mtcars[1:5, c("mpg", "cyl")]

ls_eg$kbl <- 
  ls_eg$df1 |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE,
      caption = "Kable as a list element") |> 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
  

```

## Include Table in body of report

See table \@ref(tab:kbl-as-list-element) for cross reference fails when kable is an element of a list.

```{r kbl-as-list-element, echo=FALSE}

ls_eg$kbl


```



Table \@ref(tab:kbl-in-chunk) cross reference fine.

```{r kbl-in-chunk, echo=FALSE}

  ls_eg$df1 |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE,
      caption = "Kable in chunk") |> 
  kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")

```
````

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `\@ref(tab:kbl-as-list-element)`, you need to use `\@ref(tab:dw)` to refer to the first table, since `dw` is the **chunk-label** from where the table is generated.

Comment: @shafee Thank you for that explanation. In my actual use case the list includes two kable elements. So I'll be referring to the same chunk potentially for two separate kables. I'll have to experiment with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the table labels in a different list and then pass them in a loop to `kableExtra::kbl`'s `label` argument. So the tables in the list will be created with those labels which you can use later to refer to them.

````
---
title: "Table cross references"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{booktabs}
 - \usepackage{float}
---


```{r dw, include=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(purrr)

ls_eg <- vector("list")
ls_eg$df <- list(
              mtcars[1:5, c("mpg", "cyl")], 
              mtcars[6:10, c("mpg", "cyl")]
            )

ls_eg$labels <- list("table1", "table2")

ls_eg$kbl <- purrr::map2(.x = ls_eg$df, .y = ls_eg$labels, 
            .f = \(x, y) {
              x |> 
                kbl(booktabs = TRUE,
                    caption = "Kable as a list element",
                    label = y) |> 
                kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
            })

```

## Include Table in body of report

See table \@ref(tab:table1) and \@ref(tab:table2)

```{r kbl-as-list-element, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat(ls_eg$kbl[[1]])
cat(ls_eg$kbl[[2]])
```
````

**rendered output**

[image: tables with reference]

Comment: Thank you so much; the `label` argument to `kable` is key to this.